# Select all the data from a table where the timestamp against each customer_id is maximum

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

The data is as follows and each cust_id (customer id) may or may not have multiple rows of data. Just as a sample data I have created the following.
I want to write a SQL query to get all the data of each cust_id (customer id) where the timestamp is latest.

| Cust_id | name | visit_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | "AB" | "2000-01-22 21:00:00.000000" |
| 1 | "AB1" | "2000-01-22 22:00:00.000000" |
| 2 | "MN" | "2000-01-22 22:00:00.000000" |
| 2 | "MN1" | "2000-01-22 21:00:00.000000" |
| 3 | "XY" | "2000-01-22 22:00:00.000000" |
| 3 | "XY1" | "2000-01-22 21:00:00.000000" |
| 4 | "HI" | "2000-01-22 21:00:00.000000" |

Comment: so...is it mysql, postgresql or db2?

Comment: I removed the conflicting database tags. Please tag only the DBMS you are really using.

Comment: This has been asked many times: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group+sql

Answer (score 1):

A canonical method is:

```
select te.*
from time_entry te
where te.visit_date = (select max(te2.visit_date)
                       from time_entry te2
                       where te2.cust_id = te.cust_id
                      );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM time_entry
WHERE visit_date IN(SELECT MAX(visit_date) FROM time_entry
GROUP BY cust_id)
ORDER BY cust_id;
```

The above query worked for me but I am not sure of using a group by without selecting any other column with the aggregate function.

Comment: The sue of `SELECT *` with `GROUP BY` is an abomination that is still permitted by very few databases.  It doesn't make sense, because the `SELECT` columns are incompatible with the `GROUP BY` columns.  Even if this works syntactically, this has logical errors that are too long for a comment -- basically multiple `cust_id`s can match the `in` condition.